# "Thin" JavaScript framework for cross-browser scripting?

Tags: javascript, ajax, javascript-framework

Is there a JavaScript framework that focuses on extending JavaScript by levelling the implementation differences? I don't mean a framework that simply provides the same functionality across different browsers, but something that makes non-standard browsers behave as if they were standards-compliant.

Basically I want something that does for JavaScript what `ie7.js` does for MSIE or what `html5shiv` does for HTML5 elements. Or the various workarounds for Web Sockets or Canvas.

I guess jQuery and its ilk could do the trick, but I'd prefer something that allows me to write *normal*, standards-compliant JavaScript as if there were no differences between the browsers.

EDIT: As every other answer seems to point out that, yes, jQuery is JavaScript and, yes, most JavaScript frameworks try to improve cross-browser compability, let me clarify what I mean.

The differences between JavaScript implementations across different browsers don't have much to do with the language itself these days. Apart from a few built-in methods missing in older browsers, the types mostly behave the same, too. But there are still differences, especially between the present status quo (Chrome/Firefox/Safari) and legacy versions of MSIE (i.e. MSIE 7). Most notably, the DOM tends to have less-or-more subtle peculiarities to its API.

I don't want just a framework that lets me write JavaScript that works across most browsers. Those are a dime a dozen. I want a thin layer that allows me to write code that works in modern browsers and legacy browsers alike. jQuery, Dojo, etc all go way beyond that and provide their own unique APIs instead of unifying the existing ones.

Saying "use jQuery" is like saying I should use `Rich Ajax Platform` (or other code generation frameworks) if I want to avoid cross-browser rendering differences. I don't want a "substitute", I want a "bugfix" (not literally).

EDIT2: Just to drive the point home: I'm not looking for just any framework. I'm deeply familiar with jQuery, have tried YUI and am currently considering to give Dojo a try. I don't simply want a "good" framework. I want one that fits my very specific description. It's okay if there isn't anything like it, though it'd be interesting to know why not (i.e. technical reasons, not "everybody's too busy using jQuery").

Comment: All javascript frameworks are meant to minimize the cross-browser issues amongst other things.

Comment: @Sarfraz, conceptually, yes. They're always meant to work across different browsers, but they don't do that by cleaning up the API but by providing their own.

Comment: That's just untrue...they wrap the different browser API's and deal with the inconsistencies in their implementation.  You sir are really missing the point of JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @Achilles - Yes true! jQuery doesn't make `getElementByClassName` work cross-browser, it simply provides the same functionality via a different API. I'm fully aware of the capabilities of existing frameworks, but pretending the choice of framework doesn't affect the structure of your code is quite naïve. Compare YUI, Dojo and jQuery, for example.

Comment: Must be frustrating with all the "use jQuery" answers.. I understand that you perfectly well know what jQuery and its like is and does.

Comment: Maybe you should write an example of code to explain what you mean and include some pseudocode of what you would like to have.

Comment: I get the request, but care to talk more about why you want this (vs, e.g. jQuery)? I think the reason such a thing (a library that just loads up and papers over noncompliant behavior) doesn't exist is that people generally want more than just that. Much like nobody writes Windows applications in C against the Win32 API anymore (though they did commonly back in the day), nobody really writes web pages in "raw" (even standards-compliant) browser/DOM manipulation anymore. In other words, my sense is that the time in history has passed where a library like you mention would have had an audience.

Comment: So, you want a library that overwrites IEs native, non compliant DOM methods with ones with standard behavior, and adds in the methods that don't exist in that browser? This doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Comment: @Alex JL - Exactly that. @quixoto - Yes, it's Spartan, but that's the whole point. My concern is less with the actual raw DOM manipulation (which is mostly about walking trees anyway) but with the helpers like `getElementByClassName` and such. I'm not proposing such a framework as an everyday alternative to jQuery et al, but there are cases where I'd prefer being able to just stick to the specs and have it work.

Comment: No chance. IE does not expose the prototypes of DOM nodes, so you have no way to extend them without doing it for each individual node. I don't suppose you want to be making a call to a function to standards-ify your node every time you get hold of a new node reference (e.g. `var el = someNode.nextSibling; fixUp(el); var matchingEls = el.getElementsByClassName("someclass");`)

Comment: I'd recommend having a read of this: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @Alan: OK. I think that such a "library" doesn't exist because its scope and use case really is quite limited. Not denying your desire to have one, but I think that's why nothing seems to be readily available. What you're talking about you could write yourself incrementally in a shortish amount of time if you know the browser differences and the spec.

Comment: @Tim Down: Thanks for the link. The article at least explains why it's impossible to make IE's DOM behave. Your standards-ification method sounds like jQuery's `$` though (except jQuery obviously doesn't try to mimick the DOM API). Considering how the DOM seems to be pretty much a black box, I guess the only solution would be to wrap all of it in a library and avoid direct exposure (which would be no better than using jQuery to start with). I guess the problem really is unsolvable in this case. If you had written this as answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time has passed since this question was asked, but perhaps it's of use to someone: recently, a group of developers from Financial Times set up sort of a universal polyfill that only patches the necessary parts for different browsers.. http://cdn.polyfill.io/v1/docs/

Answer (score 6):

If you're as minimalist in your thinking as your post suggests, you might try compiling your own micro-library that provides cross-browser functionality for some of the most often annoying divergences, like addEventListener vs. attachEvent, getTagsByClassName vs. no method, scrolling disparities, window dimensions, etc. Most of the Javascript disparities are actually disparities in DOM methods anyway, and the list, while long, doesn't have to be compiled all at once. Add your own cross-browser functions as they come up in your coding.

Short of that, use jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

All JavaScript libraries attempt to "level the playing field" by allowing you to write clean cross-browser compatible JavaScript code.

Some of the most popular:

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/)

[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (my personal favorite)

Comment: I'd give you a vote for being helpful by pointing me at several decent frameworks, but your answer seems to completely ignore the part where I said what I was looking for in particular. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 4):

There is no chance of achieving exactly what you want. IE does not expose the prototypes of DOM nodes, so you have no way to extend them without doing it for each individual node. Also, it's usually (maybe always?) not possible to overwrite existing read-only properties of host objects such as DOM nodes in IE, so you won't be able to fix wrongly-implemented DOM properties on DOM nodes themselves. Even if you just fix DOM methods, you'll still need to call a function to do this every time you get hold of a new node reference:

```
var el = someNode.nextSibling;
fixUp(el); // Adds missing methods to the element and fixes broken ones
var matchingEls = el.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
```

For a really good, detailed explanation of why what you want is impossible, I'd recommend having a read of this: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a simple "make browsers behave correctly" framework - they all go quite significant degrees beyond this.

That said, there's no value in re-inventing the wheel so it might be wise to invest the time in something like jQuery (perhaps using a custom minimal build), etc. whilst ensuring that there are sensible fallbacks for users with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When writing "standard" JavaScript, I tend to define my own functions that provide cross-browser implementations of commonly used features. `addEvent` and `removeEvent` (there are several implementations) are common examples of this technique. I've researched and written several functions that enable me to call one function for a specific problem, rather than feature-detect and execute the correct code at every turn.

Things like getting height, width, and offset of an element require different implementations for different browsers, but can easily be written into a function and reused wherever you need them.

So, my "solution" is largely a DIY solution. Create a file called "utilities.js" and start adding functions as you need them. `addEvent`, `removeEvent`, and a cross-browser `XMLHttpRequest` are a good place to start. Here, I'll start you off:

```
function createXHR()
{
    var xhr;
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e.message);
            xhr = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    return xhr;
}
```

That function will return an XMLHttpRequest object for use as you see fit. Enjoy.

**Edit:** Do note that this approach could theoretically crowd your namespace quite a bit. You may be best off creating a `utilities` object, and calling `utilities.createXHR`.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, http://flowjs.com/ should be quite close to what you are looking for. It's main goal: "FlowJS implements the DOM Level 3 API across all modern browsers"

Answer (score 0):

You have that with JQuery.  Using JQuery gives you the ability to query the DOM with the consistency that is lacking across the different browswer implementations.  I'd say that and ajax calls deals with the largest set of issues that people deal with in JavaScript these days.

Comment: True, but jQuery makes you write jQuery code. The framework I'm looking for would let you write JavaScript "the way it's meant to be" (i.e. plain), but cross-browser.

Comment: @Alan - There is no jQuery code. jQuery is JavaScript (and it uses plain old JavaScript syntax). Most of the cross-browser issues come in when you interact with the DOM which is what makes jQuery selectors so nice.

Comment: I'm aware jQuery is JavaScript, but it still encourages a particular syntax and code structure that is quite different from plain old JavaScript. That's what I'm referring to. Otherwise the question would be pretty pointless.

Comment: jQuery doesn't 'replace' JavaScript style; it replaces DOM.  DOM isn't JavaScript.

Comment: JQuery doesn't use a particular syntax, it's just a fluent interface.  If anything JQuery is a DSL for manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @Achilles - That's the point exactly. It provides its own API instead of unifying the existing one. By "JavaScript" I meant the browser's JavaScript API including the DOM, `XMLHttpRequest` etc. Curious experiments like `skulpt` or `processing.js` aside, the actual language doesn't depend on the framework. But conventional APIs provide too thick a layer for my taste.